# Is the C-I bond polar?

Tags: bond, electrons

Carbon and iodine have similar electronegativities. The reason quoted for the C-I bond having polarity is that iodine is more polarisable.

But what does this actually mean? Carbon distorts the electron cloud around ioidine, but how exactly does it distort the electron cloud? And how does this affect the polarity of C-I bond?

Does it, perhaps, distort the electron cloud of ioidine away. But why would it distort the electron cloud away and not towards the C-I bond where the electrons have the opportunity to experience the attraction of two nuclei as opposed to just one?

Edit: here is a quote from a textbook  (Organic chemistry, Fourth Edition by Paula Yurkanis Bruice):

> "Carbon and iodine, however, have the same
>   electronegativity. Why, then, does an alkyl halide undergo a
>   substitution reaction? We know that larger atoms are more polarizable than smaller
>   atoms. (Recall from that polarizability is a measure of how easily an
>   atom’s electron cloud can be distorted.) The high polarizability of the large iodine
>   atom causes it to react as if it were polar even though, on the basis of the electronegativity of the atoms, the bond is nonpolar."

Comment: Electronegativity is not a precise measure of anything.

Comment: If you ask this then edit out similar content [from your earlier question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134579/relationship-between-basicity-and-electron-withdrawing-ability).

Comment: I have a feeling you have an incorrect assumption - where did you get such quote and what was it exactly? What you quoted earlier doesn't say that, nor does truly mean what you implied.

Comment: @Mithoron Thanks for the feedback, I have added a quote to the question. I have also edited the other question like you have asked me to.

Comment: You know what? Maybe just read a better textbook... One thing is that it's using somewhat strange reasoning 2) You're getting to some weird conclusions further messing things up. Being polarizable  has like nothing to do with being *good leaving group*. Also iodine has a bit higher electronegativity then C - you're so literal minded that reading a table of values may be a better idea.